# Downloading entire site locally with httrack

Tags: admin

I had a bit of a scare with a malformed database last night which got me to getting onto making sure I have so many redundant backups of my site that I am covered in the event of the server dying, my home backup server dying, etc. :)  That said, I am trying to use `httrack` to download the entire site, but I run into a case where it ONLY gets the root site (for example):

`test.mylovelysite.com`

But I need it to crawl:

`test.mylovelysite.com/page/2/` etc., etc., etc.

I can go and tell it to download each page manually, but what I'm trying to do is:

- Capture all the site content locally:

  - Pictures
  - Comments
  - Videos

I can open the downloaded files in Chrome and the only local page is the root page right now.  Any link just points me back to the actual site itself I am trying to backup.

I've tried the export function within Wordpress, but I'm not looking for an XML file, I'm looking for an entire local backup of the site.  I have SFTP ac

Comment: httrack should be able to crawl your site and get HTML copies for you but if something went wrong with the site putting things back together from that HTML version would be nearly as hard as just starting over.

Comment: This is essentially httrack question and not WP one. As per answers it's not suitable for backup and you'll get better results using dedicated WP backup solution or backing up files and database conventionally.

Comment: This is NOT a httrack question at all.  The OP specifically mentions the database then explains how the first attempt involved downloading the FILES.   HTTrack cannot access the DB; only the files.  The proper answer is given below, by @Ahmad.  Except that now it is May 2018 and the best plug-in would be Updraft Plus.  Since this question got closed I can't post this as a proper answer.  This comment will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Wordpress backup plugins like [XCloner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/) or [Duplicator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/), both will backup the entire site files along with the database with easy restore or copy of your site on a different server or on local machine.

Comment: May 2018 - UpdraftPlus is the go-to plug-in like this, now.

Answer (score 2):

HTtrack will only download the HTML source of your page. If your online site goes down, the HTtrack version will not be appropriate to replace your site with. If you want your local backup to be powered by WordPress, and not just a static site, then you need to download your site using SFTP, and then export your database tables using phpMyAdmin.

If you want to *view* your site locally, you can setup XAMPP or something similar and copy your files and import your database back. Tom Ewer has written a [good tutorial for setting up XAMPP on Windows](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-wordpress-website-in-windows-with-xampp).